# How to launch Pygame for Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Pygame does not seem to work for me. I have installed it but I can't run any applications that use it, nor can I import it myself.

```
PS C:\Users\Mcmillan\Desktop\mario-level-1-master> python mario_level_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mario_level_1.py", line 10, in <module>
    from data.main import main
  File "C:\Users\Mcmillan\Desktop\mario-level-1-master\data\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import setup,tools
  File "C:\Users\Mcmillan\Desktop\mario-level-1-master\data\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    SFX   = tools.load_all_sfx(os.path.join("resources","sound"))
  File "C:\Users\Mcmillan\Desktop\mario-level-1-master\data\tools.py", line 143, in load_all_sfx
    effects[name] = pg.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(directory, fx))
```

This is what came up when I tried to run a game.

Comment: what happens when you open an interpreter and type import pygame?

Comment: That can't be the whole error either can it?  What error is actually being thrown?

Comment: The problem is in `effects[name] = pg.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(directory, fx))`

Comment: I'm betting this is a file not found exception

Comment: So this is embaressing.I've been getting pygame errors for weeks and now they suddenly fix themselves. Right after I posted here. That was the whole error I got from running the game via powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get something like this..

```
>>> 1 / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

The last line tells you the actual problem.  Try using the normal cmd shell.  I can't imagine why but you seem to be missing important information in your trace.  All you are getting is where the error is, not what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can always easily download the binary and run it from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame